# An error message cannot be displayed because an optional resource assembly containing it cannot be found

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

I am working on windows mobile 6, i created one application in VS 2005 using Sqlserver compact sp1.This application running on emulator fine.But when i deply my cab file on real device.i am getting this type of error:-

An error message cannot be displayed because an optional resource assembly containing it cannot be found.

Could any one help me....
Thanks..........

Answer (score 14, accepted):

String resources for some error messages are not installed by default on mobile devices (for space saving reasons I would guess). You can install these resources manually if you wish.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351657.aspx):

> To install .NET Compact Framework
>   resource files
>
> 1. Verify if the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 or later
>      is installed on your computer. If
>      installed, proceed to Step 3.
> 2. Download and install the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2
>      on your computer. The setup file for
>      the .NET Compact Framework 2.0 Service
>      Pack 2 can be found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17981).
> 3. On your computer, browse to the location \Program
>      Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\Diagnostics,
>      and then copy the appropriate resource
>      CAB file to the mobile device.
> 4. On the mobile device, locate and tap the CAB file to install the
>      resource pack.

After you have installed the resource files the device will show the message for the error that occurs.

Comment: Since I just got the same error and googling it brought me here: The download-link in this post and in MSDN seem both to be outdated, you can still find the `.NET Compact Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2` at the [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17981)